# C++: Is initializing a static local variable with a IIFE thread-safe?

Tags: c++, lambda, thread-safety, iife

Is the following code thread-safe? (Using a IIFE to initialize a static local variable.)

```
int MyFunc(){

static int Val = ([]()
   {
   return 1 + 2 + 3 + 4; // Real code is more complex, but thread-safe
   })();

return Val;

}
```

Comment: Very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939484/is-initialization-of-local-static-function-object-thread-safe), possibly a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. C++11 (and above) guarantees no data races between multiple threads trying to initialize a static local variable. If the code inside your lambda is thread-safe, the initialization will be as well.

Using a lambda, function call, or constructor doesn't change the thread-safety of the initialization.

Comment: what do you mean by `If the code inside your lambda is thread-safe` -- shouldn't the lambda be called only from the first thread reaching the initializer ?

Comment: @AndreHolzner Correct, but the code inside the lambda might for instance call functions that aren’t reentrant, and which are being called concurrently elsewhere.